# Having Multiple Styling in the Same Google Sheets Cell

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have 4 different arrays consisting of names. I am trying to merge them splitted by comma, inside of the A1 Cell. The thing is I want all names to have their own styling according to their array. For example, array1 will have red color, array 2 green, array3 orange, and array4 gray with strike-through line. I was able to achieve it in different cells, but couldn't apply it to one cell.

I was able to achieve it in different cells, but couldn't apply it to one cell.

Comment: Have you researched `RichTextValue()`? [Doc ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have four arrays containing text. You want to join the arrays but format the respective substrinbgs separately.

The key method is `setTextStyle(startOffset, endOffset, textStyle)` [Doc ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder#settextstylestartoffset,-endoffset,-textstyle)

The documentation provides an example that I have adapted here.
No doubt there are ways of linking array names and colours, but I have made this answer as single as possible into order to demonstrate the process. The OP, or others, can make the script more dynamic if need be.

---

```
function colorSubString() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")

  // declare arrays
  var array1 = ["This"]
  var array2 = ["child"]
  var array3 = ["is carrying"]
  var array4 = ["apples"]

  // create temporary array to buikld a complete string
  var dataArray = new Array
  dataArray = dataArray.concat(array1,array2,array3,array4);
  dataArray = dataArray.join(' ');
  // Logger.log(dataArray) // DEBUG

  // save to "BEFORE" cell
  sheet.getRange("B1").setValue(dataArray);

  // build the foreground color styles
  var redFC = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setForegroundColor("red").build()
  var greenFC = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setForegroundColor("green").build()
  var orangeFC = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setForegroundColor("darkorange").build()
  var grayFC = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setForegroundColor("gray").build()

  // apply the styles 
  var value = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(dataArray)
    .setTextStyle(0, array1[0].length, redFC)
    .setTextStyle((array1[0].length+1), (array1[0].length+1+array2[0].length), greenFC)
    .setTextStyle(array1[0].length+1+array2[0].length+1, array1[0].length+1+array2[0].length+1+array3[0].length, orangeFC)
    .setTextStyle(array1[0].length+1+array2[0].length+1+array3[0].length+1, array1[0].length+1+array2[0].length+1+array3[0].length+1+array4[0].length, grayFC)
 
  // save to the 'AFTER' cell
  sheet.getRange("B2").setRichTextValue(value.build());
}
```

---

**RESULTS**

[image: snapshot]